# Image, union and intersections in category of simplicial sets

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\Delta$ denote the simplicial category and $\textbf{sSet}$ the category $\text{Func}(\Delta^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set})$. If $X$ is a simplicial set, a simplicial subset of $X$ is a simplicial set $Y$ such that $Y_n\subset X_n$ $(n\in\mathbb{N})$ and $X(\alpha)|_{Y_m}=Y(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha:[n]\rightarrow[m]\in\Delta$.

Now the author writes

> We can form images of morphisms of simplicial sets, and unions and
> intersections of simplicial subsets, in the obvious way.

I'm not sure exactly what this means.

Let $u:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of simplicial sets. What would the "image of $u$" have to be? An element of $\textbf{Set}$, e.g. $\bigsqcup_n u([n])(X_n)$?

If $Y,Z$ are simplicial subsets of $X$, then presumably their union should be another simplicial subset of $X$. In that case, is it the functor that send $[n]$ to $Y_n\sqcup Z_n$? But it's not clear how $Y_n\sqcup Z_n$ can be a subset of $X_n$...If we replace $\sqcup$ by $\cup$, it won't be obvious what the image of $\alpha:[n]\rightarrow[m]$ can be.

Finally, what should the intersection of simplicial subsets $Y,Z$ of $X$ be? Again it's a functor from $\Delta^{\text{op}}$ to $\textbf{Set}$. I am inclined to say that it sends $[n]$ to $Y_n\cap Z_n$. Here again I have no idea what the image of $\alpha:[n]\rightarrow[m]$ should be.

Comment: You do everything separately over each $[n]$, what is the problem? Imagine having two sets hanging over each $[n]$ (with some arrows over each $\alpha$) and regarding them as one set.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Let's take the case of intersection. What do you propose to define as the intersection of two simplicial subsets $Y,Z$ of $X$?

Comment: What do you mean about "the image of $\alpha : [n] \to [m]$"?  This is not part of the definition of simplicial subset that you gave; instead, you have the "compatibility" condition, and you just need to verify that it holds for $[n] \mapsto Y_n \cup Z_n$ respectively $[n] \mapsto Y_n \cap Z_n$ (and along the way in both cases, you will make use of the hypothesis that the compatibility condition holds for both $Y$ and $Z$).

Comment: Oh, now I see, the definition technically requires you to have a simplicial set in the first place.  Well, as long as you have some mapping $Y : \Delta^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ where $Y_n \subseteq X_n$ for each $n$, and satisfying the compability condition that for each $\alpha : [n] \to [m]$, whenever $x \in Y_m$, then $X(\alpha)(x) \in Y_n$ -- then the restriction of $X(\alpha)$ automatically maps $Y_m \to Y_n$ and those restrictions still make up the functoriality part of a simplicial set $Y$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I guess for intersection I can take either $Y(\alpha)$ or $Z(\alpha)$, as the image of $\alpha$. But surely I have to use disjoint union for the union of simplicial sets: then the relation $Y_n\sqcup Z_n\subset X_n$ would be nonsense, unless $\subset$ is taken to mean that there is a monomorphism and not the set-theoretic subset relation.

Comment: For intersection: yes; or you can say you use the restriction of $X(\alpha)$, since $Y$ and $Z$ being simplicial subsets already means that both $Y(\alpha)$ and $Z(\alpha)$ are restrictions of $X(\alpha)$ anyway.  And for the union of simplicial subsets: you definitely want to use the simplicial subset $A$ where $A_n = Y_n \cup Z_n$ and again $A(\alpha)$ is the restriction of $X(\alpha)$.  As you say, $Y_n \sqcup Z_n$ won't be a subset of $X_n$ in general.

Comment: @DanielSchepler oh right, now I get exactly what you're suggesting; this will trivialize the compatibility relations. One last question, if you don't mind: is my suggestion for "image of morphism of simplicial sets" correct?